# When I activate the virtual environment in python (PyCharm) my terminal doesn't see docker, git and bash commands

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenv, python-venv

I am using windows 10 as my OS and for the development, I use PyCharm IDE.
And I am facing an issue with Virtual Environment. When I activate venv my terminal doesn't recognize docker, git, bash, and probably many other commands. When venv is not active all works fine, all commands are recognized.

Example:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.27.0.windows.1
```

But when I activate my virtual env:

```
$ git --version
bash: git: command not found
(env)
```

And my question how I can solve it. Is it something with my PyCharm configuration or maybe something with system environment variables?

Updated:
Here are my terminal settings in pycharm
[image]

Comment: Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux or WSL in this scenario?

Comment: I am using bash as my main terminal on windows. I updated my post with a screenshot. So it's the WSL case.

Comment: I feel this may be related to the fact that you are using Git Bash as your shell. Have you tried using the Git Bash shell outside of the PyCharm environment? Does the same problem occur when you do?

Answer (score 2):

You have to uncheck the "Activate virtualenv" in your terminal settings.

Comment: Wouldn't this be contrary to what they want if they're trying to use a virtual environment, since it'd remove access to any tool installed to the virtualenv?